# Having trouble with getting darkmode.js to work properly with media queries - any solutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am having trouble with darkmode.js
I have this "show" class and its darkmode.js property setup like this:

```
\`    .show {
position: relative;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
width: 50%;

.darkmode--activated .show {
position: relative;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
width: 50%;
}\`
```

Then, I created a media query and changed the above details in it as follows:

```
\`.show {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 70px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.darkmode--activated .show {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 70px 15px 0px 15px;
}\`
```

Now, if I am commmenting out the width property, then it turns to dark but doesn't turn back. And when I don't comment it out, the darkmode.js button doesn't work at all.

please help me find a solution to this problem.

I was expecting it to seamlessly change from dark mode to light mode and vice versa.